# Why ng-app not ng-module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand that ng-app initializes a module in AngularJS as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

But when I teach this to someone new to AngularJS or watch a video, instructors inevitable fumble over the inconsistency in the terminology between app and module.  AngularJS is so well thought out as a framework that I'm surprised it hasn't changed to:

```
var app = angular.app('myApp', []);
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

OR

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);
<html ng-module="myModule">
```

Has anyone been following the project long enough to know the history on this part of the framework?

Comment: if somone claims to be angular instructor in a video and fumbles over this part... avoid them ! Undertandably easy to forget to add it but convention isn't difficult

Comment: This question got me wondering if I could create the ngModule directive myself without the limitations of ngApp. This is what I came up with: http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2014/04/angularjs-getting-around-ngapp-limitations-with-ngmodule/

Comment: Great Question. Indeed, when I first started, I just used `ng-module` & it took some time to realise that it was `ng-app`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think Craig is asking what does `ng-app` do or how does it work.

I think he's asking why did the people that created angular name that directive `ng-app`. Why didn't they name it `ng-module`. `ng-module` would be easier to understand.

For example `ng-controller` should name a controller, `ng-module` should name a module. The `angular` methods to create them are named `module()` and `controller()`, there is no method or entity called "app".

I tend to agree with Craig. That said if I were go speculate why they named it `ng-app` I would think it's because you are only allowed to have one `ng-app` directive in your HTML. If you wanted to have more than one module associated with your HTML page you can do it programmatically.

So `ng-app` is more of a utility to bootstrap your HTML with a module, it is not a generic way to associate modules with your HTML.

If you look at the documentation that's what it suggests:

> Use this directive to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application. The
>   ngApp directive designates the root element of the application and is
>   typically placed near the root element of the page - e.g. on the
>    or  tags.
>
> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define
>   the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple
>   applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them
>   using angular.bootstrap instead. AngularJS applications cannot be
>   nested within each other.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

All that said if you want an `ng-module` directive you could always write your own to wrap the `angular.bootstrap()` function. You can find more details and code about how to do this on a blog post I wrote about it: [AngularJS: Getting around ngApp limitations with ngModule](http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2014/04/angularjs-getting-around-ngapp-limitations-with-ngmodule/)

Answer (score 7):

`ng-app` means: That page has Angular in it!

`ng-app="module"` means: That page has Angular in it and necessary controls/services/etc are defined in that module.

Answer (score 4):

`ng-app` defines the `main` or `bootstrap` module of your application, which should perform the initialization task of your application. There may be case where at run time you want to decide what which should be the main module of your application. Like in java you have many methods and classes but you define one `main` method as starting point. Similarly, in angular you have many module, however, you define one module as the starting point of application.

Comment: I second that. `ng-module` would be misleading, making you think that you should have as many `ng-module` as you have modules.