# angular argument is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my html page I get the below error

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'quickReportController' is not a function, got undefined
```

I searched and found **a lot** of solutions but not none of them was helping

**The html file**

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    ...
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>   

    <script>
    </script>   
</head>

<body style="font-family: tahoma;" ng-app>

<div class="container bootcards-container" ng-module="myModule">

    <div class="row" ng-controller="quickReportController">
        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var module = angular.module('myModule', []);
        module.controller("quickReportController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.name = "dd";
        }]);
    }());  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missed to define `ng-app`, it should be `ng-app='myModule'`,
only using

```
 <body style="font-family: tahoma;" ng-app>
```

will try to find global controller named `quickReportController`, ehich is not global.

Replace with this:

```
   <body style="font-family: tahoma;" ng-app='myModule'>
```

---

Also You are trying to define `ng-module` and nd `ng-app`, so read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22865917/3556874

Comment: Thanks, After changing to your code, I got the fine result  in Chrome, but I got this error in **IE** (just in IE), Have you any idea? **0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module atlas due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**

Comment: @Disposer.. if you could reproduce the problem in fiddle or plunkr?

Comment: Its working in IE, but as Im working with visual studio, the error makes the IDE to break for exception, but its working fine, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use ng-app="myModule" and remove ng-module from your html?